# gpshell "delete_key" command return 6a80 (Wrong data)

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I imported several GlobalPlatform keys in my javacard with different key version. i can create secure channel by new key but when i want delete one of them i receive sw=6a80 result. My script is:

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect -readerNumber 1
select -AID A000000018434D00
open_sc -security 0 -keyind 0 -keyver 02 -mac_key 47454d5850524553534f53414d504c45-enc_key 47454d5850524553534f53414d504c45-kek_key 47454d5850524553534f53414d504c45// Open secure channel
delete_key -keyver 08 -keyind 0
get_status -element 40
card_disconnect
release_contex
```

I also try second script which open secure channel with same key but the result is sw = 6a80,

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect -readerNumber 1
select -AID A000000018434D00
open_sc -security 0 -keyind 0 -keyver 08 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -kek_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f // Open secure channel
delete_key -keyver 08 -keyind 0
get_status -element 40
card_disconnect
release_context
```

the apdu trace is:

```
Command --> 80CA006600
Wrapped command --> 80CA006600
Response <-- 664C734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864
886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040105650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012
A026E01029000
Command --> 8050020008919F9B915C23C5D600
Wrapped command --> 8050020008919F9B915C23C5D600
Response <-- 4D0022840106A57C224F020137AFC43375EF54A1A60DF8A01B351A189000
Command --> 8482000010E61BDA493C17D649ED414E4AD2356F3C
Wrapped command --> 8482000010E61BDA493C17D649ED414E4AD2356F3C
Response <-- 9000
delete_key -keyver 08 -keyind 0
Command --> 80E4000006D00100D2010800
Wrapped command --> 80E4000006D00100D2010800
Response <-- 6A80
delete_key() return 0x80206A80 (6A80: Wrong data / Incorrect values in command d
ata.)
get_status -element 40
Command --> 80F24000024F0000
Wrapped command --> 80F24000024F0000
Response <-- 09A0000003080000100007049000
```

Anyone can help me. Thanks a lot.